# Не работает proxy в pyTelegramBotApi

Tags: python, telebot

Я разрабатываю своего бота телеграм для игры `Pathfinder` у меня есть домашний сервер(свободный ноутбук) для его установки. Для работы этого бота нужно использовать прокси(из-за блокировки). Хочется не устанавливать VPN на сервер,а использовать встроенную в библиотеку `pyTelegramBotApi` возможность использовать прокси. При использовании VPN все работает.

Фрагмент кода:

```py
PROXY = 'socks5://148.72.209.6:57437'
apihelper.proxy = {'https': PROXY}
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)
```

Если я пытаюсь запустить с прокси выводит такое сообщение:

```
(util.py:65 PollingThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "InvalidSchema occurred, args=('Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Coding\BotsTelegram\SecondBot\env\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 59, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Coding\BotsTelegram\SecondBot\env\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 276, in __retrieve_updates
    updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1), timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Coding\BotsTelegram\SecondBot\env\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 246, in get_updates
    json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates)
  File "C:\Coding\BotsTelegram\SecondBot\env\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 180, in get_updates
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
  File "C:\Coding\BotsTelegram\SecondBot\env\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 54, in _make_request
    timeout=(connect_timeout, read_timeout), proxies=proxy)
  File "C:\Coding\BotsTelegram\SecondBot\env\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Coding\BotsTelegram\SecondBot\env\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Coding\BotsTelegram\SecondBot\env\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 412, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "C:\Coding\BotsTelegram\SecondBot\env\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 309, in get_connection
    proxy_manager = self.proxy_manager_for(proxy)
  File "C:\Coding\BotsTelegram\SecondBot\env\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 189, in proxy_manager_for
    **proxy_kwargs
  File "C:\Coding\BotsTelegram\SecondBot\env\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 47, in SOCKSProxyManager
    raise InvalidSchema("Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.")
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.
"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Ян\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.8.30787\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 43, in <module>
    main(ptvsdArgs)
  File "c:\Users\Ян\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.8.30787\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 432, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\Ян\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.8.30787\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 316, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='__main__')
  File "C:\Users\Ян\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Users\Ян\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\Ян\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Coding\BotsTelegram\SecondBot\main.py", line 50, in <module>
    bot.polling()
  File "C:\Coding\BotsTelegram\SecondBot\env\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 389, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)
  File "C:\Coding\BotsTelegram\SecondBot\env\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 412, in __threaded_polling
    polling_thread.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Coding\BotsTelegram\SecondBot\env\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 78, in raise_exceptions
    six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])
  File "C:\Coding\BotsTelegram\SecondBot\env\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Coding\BotsTelegram\SecondBot\env\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 59, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Coding\BotsTelegram\SecondBot\env\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 276, in __retrieve_updates
    updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1), timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Coding\BotsTelegram\SecondBot\env\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 246, in get_updates
    json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates)
  File "C:\Coding\BotsTelegram\SecondBot\env\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 180, in get_updates
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
  File "C:\Coding\BotsTelegram\SecondBot\env\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 54, in _make_request
    timeout=(connect_timeout, read_timeout), proxies=proxy)
  File "C:\Coding\BotsTelegram\SecondBot\env\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Coding\BotsTelegram\SecondBot\env\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Coding\BotsTelegram\SecondBot\env\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 412, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "C:\Coding\BotsTelegram\SecondBot\env\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 309, in get_connection
    proxy_manager = self.proxy_manager_for(proxy)
  File "C:\Coding\BotsTelegram\SecondBot\env\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 189, in proxy_manager_for
    **proxy_kwargs
  File "C:\Coding\BotsTelegram\SecondBot\env\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 47, in SOCKSProxyManager
    raise InvalidSchema("Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.")
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас нет модуля `pysocks`, необходимого для работы с протоколом `socks5`.

Установите его, введя в консоли (или терминале):

```
pip install pysocks
```

Comment: Я установил и импортировал, но теперь выдает эту ошибку
File "C:\Coding\BotsTelegram\SecondBot\env\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 504, in send
    raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: SOCKSHTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot928030709:AAHu1_-4RvfQKFe6tVpLu8MVjoaefn1cl3g/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.contrib.socks.SOCKSHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000143161790C8>, 'Connection to api.telegram.org timed out. (connect timeout=3.5)'))

Comment: Эта ошибка говорит о том, что превышено время ожидания. Возможно, у Вас нерабочий `proxy`. Замените его и попробуйте ещё раз. Ещё можно попробовать заменить протокол на `socks5h`.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало, нашел рабочий прокси и заработало

Comment: @Ian, а что именно вы использовали для proxy?